# Imprimir cuatro JPanels de un programa JAVA SWING en una sola pagina mediante PrinterJob

Tags: java, java-swing, impresión

Aprovechando que mi aplicación JAVA SWING de la cual quiero hacer un informe, (Imprimir los datos para tenerlos en formato físico) tiene una apariencia muy lograda y trabajada que podría aprovechar imprimiendo los JPanel que muestran la información de mi programa.

He llegado al punto en que consigo imprimir los 4 paneles (JPanels) que conforman mi programa, aquí os dejo el código:

---------Esta es la clase que se encarga de imprimir el jpanel que contiene todos mis datos--------------

```
public class Imprimir_Documento implements Printable{
private JPanel ComponenteSwing;
private double escalaX,escalaY;
public Imprimir_Documento(JPanel contentPane, double x, double y) {
    ComponenteSwing=contentPane;
    escalaX = x;
    escalaY = y;
}
public void DocumentoAImprimir(JFrame texto,double escalax, double escalay){

}
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page){
    if (page > 0) {
    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
g2d.scale(escalaX, escalaY);
ComponenteSwing.printAll(g2d);
return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

}
```

---------Aquí dejo la llamada que hago desde mi JFrame y lo que le mando a imprimir-------

```
 PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        Book libro = new Book();

        libro.append(new Imprimir_Documento(panel_1, 0.25, 0.75), printJob.defaultPage());
        libro.append(new Imprimir_Documento(panel_2, 0.25, 0.75), printJob.defaultPage());
        libro.append(new Imprimir_Documento(panel_3, 0.25, 0.75), printJob.defaultPage());
        libro.append(new Imprimir_Documento(panel_4, 0.25, 0.75), printJob.defaultPage());

        printJob.setPageable(libro);

        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (Exception PrinterException) {
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, PrinterException.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Con lo que he hecho hasta ahora (lo que veis) consigo imprimir los 4 paneles que quiero pero con un inconveniente, se imprime cada JPanel en una hoja distinta y lo que quiero conseguir es que se imprimir los 4 JPanels en una misma pagina, uno debajo de otro.

Este es el punto que no logro conseguir, si alguien puede aportar algo seria de gran ayuda, gracias por la atención.

La pregunta exacta seria:

¿QUE CAMBIO HE DE HACER PARA PODER IMPRIMIR LOS 4 JPANELS EN UNA MISMA HOJA? (en caso de que no entrasen, seguiría en una segunda hoja).

Comment: Amigo, es la misma pregunta del 5 de abril http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60796/imprimir-jpanels-de-un-programa-java-swing-en-una-sola-pagina-mediante-printerjo

Comment: Hola, si que la es, gracias por el aviso. Pero la otra pregunta me la han cerrado, pensaba que si se encontraba en ese estado no era accesible para el resto, o por lo menos que no me iban a poder responderme.